# How to grab data (titles, thumbnails and custom fields) from multiple posts to populate a new array efficiently?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query-posts, query, google-maps

I need to know the most efficient method to grab 3 pieces of data from from multiple posts:

- Post title
- Thumbnail
- Custom Field

I am attempting to build a Google map of posts using data stored in WP posts. Each post has geo coordinates and a thumbnail. I want to pull the title, geo custom field and thumbnail and use this data to build points of interest on a map. The posts are stored as a custom post type called listings.

Here is a demo: http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/map/

Here is my query code:

```
$args=array( 'showposts' => 45 );
query_posts( $args );
```

Currently this is failing to query anymore than 45 posts. I have over 400 listings that I would like to query. Not sure why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! Turns out the problem with query_posts failing here was due to my PHP memory_limit. I changed it from 8mb to 128mb and the problem goes away.